# How to create Dataframe with the columns names being as a part of a csv file path?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a root folder

```
/home/project/data
```

With multiple folders in it with and ultimate paths to csv files:

```
/home/project/data/2020-12-05/John_Smith/data.csv
/home/project/data/2020-12-05/Robert_White/data.csv
/home/project/data/2020-12-06/John_Smith/data.csv
/home/project/data/2020-12-06/Sam_Walberg/data.csv
/home/project/data/2020-12-06/Garry_Oswald/data.csv
...
```

I was managed to create a Dataframe containing all csv files concatenated using the following code:

```
full_path = []
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        full_path.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
dfs = [pd.read_csv(csv_path) for csv_path in full_path]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Result:

```
df=
pr_id   quantity
0   27  4
1   89  1
2   33  2
3   8   3
4   16  1
...
```

But I am now struggling to add the respective date+name to the Dataframe, so it would look like this:

```
df=
pr_id quantity name date
0   27  4 John_Smith 2020-12-05
1   89  1 Robert_White 2020-12-05
2   33  2 John_Smith 2020-12-06
3   8   3 Sam_Walberg 2020-12-06
4   16  1 Garry_Oswald 2020-12-06
...
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pathlib`, you can go 1 & 2 directories up and get the `name` and `date`. Since this involves two things, an explicit for loop might be more readable than the list comprehension:

```
from pathlib import Path

# ...above are the same
dfs = []
for csv_path in full_path:
    # generate a `Path` object and get parents
    p = Path(csv_path)
    parents = p.parents

    # get the desired values from "parent" dirs
    name = parents[0].name
    date = parents[1].name

    # read in the CSV as is
    frame = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    
    # assign the `name` and `date` columns
    frame["name"] = name
    frame["date"] = date

    # store in the list
    dfs.append(frame)

# lastly concating as you did
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Or equivalently, the list comprehension counterpart is:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(csv_path).assign(name=csv_path.parents[0].name,
                                    date=csv_path.parents[1].name)
       for csv_path in map(Path, full_path)]

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

where we use `assign` to put new columns to each dataframe.

It depends on you to choose between explicit for loop or list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like...

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
csvs = glob('/home/project/data/*/*/data.csv')

for csv in csvs:
    date = csv.split('/')[-2]
    name = csv.split('/')[-3]
    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    df['name'] = name
    df['date'] = date
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df])
```